# Dependent variable is continuous and categorical - how to regress?

Tags: multiple-regression, dependent-variable

My research is about password safety. As dependent variable I have the number of attempts a software needed to crack the respective passwords. This results in values in a range from approx. 1e+5 to 1e+12. Unfortunately a substantial part of the passwords couldn't be cracked by the software but I would like to integrate these in my analysis.

An obvious solution to this would be to conduct a logistic regression. However, I don't want to lose the information of the distribution of the cracked passwords.

My idea was, to build something like a pseudo-continuous scale from 1 to 14. 1e+0 <= attempts < 1e+1 would be 1, 1e+1 <= attempts < 1e+2 would be 2 and so on until 13. The even stronger passwords (not being cracked by the software) would be given the value 14.

Is this possible and what would be the limitations of this procedure?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to construct this as length given it was cracked times the probability it was cracked+probability it was not cracked times number of attempts?  Then you fully account for both cases.  You also preserve the distribution for the case where cracked.  You do need to account for the fact you have a stopping rule.  It may not be that the software cannot crack the passwords, it may be that you quit too soon.  You do need to split this into two probability statements.

Comment: You have right censored data.  You could model this using some form of parametric or non-parametric survival model, e.g. survreg or coxph functions in R.

Comment: Thank you @Dave. I am not sure if I fully understand what you mean. Let's assume the probability to crack the password is .8 and the software took 1e+13 attempts to crack every password. For a cracked password (1e+5 attempts) the length would be .8 * 1e+5 + .2 * 1e+13 and for a not cracked the length would be 1e+13. Correct?

Comment: Sorry,  there is a typo.  It was in the middle of the night.  It should be the count times the probability it should be the probability of achieving that count times the probability of it being cracked.  You then get a distribution over the successful one that properly accounts for the probability of a password not being cracked.